# Why does every maven project on eclipse automatically have a junit dependency preconfigured?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am new to maven and Junit. I downloaded maven 3.5.4 and extracted it. Added a 'M2_HOME' environment variable and added in the 'path' environment variable the path right upto the bin folder of the extracted maven file. I then started eclipse and created a new maven project and the pom.xml file already had a 2 dependencies(one was junit ). I wanted to understand how did the maven project automatically load this junit dependency?

Comment: Did you use an archetype to create the Maven project?

Comment: The M2_HOME is nowhere described only PATH entry is needed. Please show the pom file...

Comment: I used maven-archtype-quickstart

Comment: <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

Answer (score 1):

The JUnit dependency is linked to the archetype selected when you create the project. Which archetype did you select when creating the project? Also note that this dependency can be removed if not neccessary...

Comment: i used maven-archtype-quickstart. Does it happen because of this?

Comment: Yes definitely. I use the same one for work purposes and the JUnit dependency is always pulled in.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much.